# How to move a .model (For Beginner)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, i'm new here, but I made my *.model* wheelchair.
And now I want to move it using keyboard or something else, but I
don't know what I need to do now. Waiting for some help...
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58878/how-to-move-a-.model-(for-beginner)/) by [Marlon Rocha](https://answers.ros.org/users/4496/marlon-rocha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2013-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you start from the [turtlesim tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics)

What you need in the end is to have some logic behind your graphical model, that way you can move it around with the keyboard.

Otherwise you may just publish a static tf once you've built an URDF for your model, and have RVIZ display it.

---

Originally posted by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) with karma: 859 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0